# Footer.php not showing?

Tags: templates

Here is my index.php file, for some reason the footer.php isn't being loaded through

really weird, its in the directory of my theme, what could be causing this?

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

 <div id="content">

 <?php query_posts('cat=-15'); ?>
 <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="entry">
     <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
     <?php
     if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
     <?php } else {
     } ?>     
    </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>


 <?php else : ?>

  <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
  <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
  <?php get_search_form(); ?>

 <?php endif; ?>

 </div><!--//content-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The code snippet above just does not show my full index.php I'm afraid.

Comment: What could cause my footer.php not to pull through?

Comment: REALLY weird. If I delete my footer.php it shows the footer.php from a theme that doesn't even exist!

Comment: We would definitely need more info to help you on this one.. can you pastebin your index.php?

Comment: Here is my paste bin: http://pastebin.com/qSaJDMxK and if you look at wackywardrobe.com forward slash dev, thank you..

Comment: @tjcss: Can you post the content of your `footer.php` too? If you delete your version, [`get_footer()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/general-template.php#L53) falls back on [an internal version](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/theme-compat/footer.php).

Comment: Is footer.php readable by the webserver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer)

> If the theme contains no footer.php file then the footer from the default theme wp-includes/theme-compat/footer.php will be included.

Chances are that something is wrong with your footer.php, and there's nothing to render - ie it's being called, but it's not doing what's expected. .

Can you paste your footer.php?

Comment: Yep sure, here is the pastebin of my footer.php: http://pastebin.com/4vfC4vgt

Comment: @tjcss This should be the approved answer?

Answer (score 0):

Right, sorry about this but I've figured it out.

My php syntax for echo-ing the date was completely wrong, so I've fixed that using the php documentation and it's all sorted now.

It was: `<?php echo "date"(Y); ?>`

But should be: `<?php echo date("Y"); ?>` thanks for all your help, didn't think for one minute that would be the problem, sorry.

Comment: Like I said - there was something wrong with your footer.php!